# What are the benefits of using windowing in Apache Beam?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

For a streaming job, if we implement windowing like Fixed Windowing. **Will it help in terms of performance or scalling?** 
I have checked windowing documentation but it doesn't mention anything about performance improvement or scalling improvements.
 
We have a job which will be consuming events which are from different services we don't really want to group them as they sinks independetly of each other.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowing is a fundamental concept that helps in dividing an unbounded collection of data into finite, manageable subsets called windows. The concept of windowing is used to group and process data based on time or other criteria, enabling time-based aggregations, sessionization, and more. It plays a crucial role in handling streaming and batch data processing scenarios.
Since Windowing involves grouping and easy calculations using aggregate functions over the fixed windows, it can be said that windowing does help in performance.  
Official documentation on windowing can be found [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing).

Comment: I think group elements and processing at once for batch does help in optimzations/performance.